# Searching for a more elegant xsl for parsing a nested xml with variable elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got this xml that i want to convert to another xml.

What i would like to do is define a `<xsl:value-of select=""/>` that gets the value from `<waarde>` when `<nummer>` is '0110'.
When there's no value for `<waarde>` the complete `<rubriek>` element is absent from the xml.
I need to know if the element is missing so i can create an empty element in the resulting .xml.

There could be multiple `<persoon>`elements in the source xml, some or all of them containing a `<rubriek>` with a `<nummer>` containing '0110'.
In that situation i want all the values from the corresponding `<waarde>` elements, and they should show up in the destination xml as `<waarde1></waarde1> <waarde2></waarde2`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:gbavAntwoord xmlns:ns2="http://www.competent.nl/gbav/v1">
            <identificatie>
                <indicatie>xx</indicatie>
                <interneAfnemer/>
                <gebruiker>xx</gebruiker>
                <profielNaam>xx</profielNaam>
                <internKenmerk/>
            </identificatie>
            <resultaten>
                <persoon>
                    <categorieen>
                        <categorie>
                            <nummer>01</nummer>
                            <naam>Persoon</naam>
                            <rubrieken>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0110</nummer>
                                    <naam>A-nummer</naam>
                                    <waarde>1234567</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>1234567</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0120</nummer>
                                    <naam>BSN</naam>
                                    <waarde>1234567</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>1234567</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                            </rubrieken>
                        </categorie>
                        <categorie>
                            <nummer>02</nummer>
                            <naam>Ouder1</naam>
                            <rubrieken>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0110</nummer>
                                    <naam>A-nummer</naam>
                                    <waarde>4567890</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>4567890</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0120</nummer>
                                    <naam>BSN</naam>
                                    <waarde>4567890</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>4567890</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                            </rubrieken>
                        </categorie>
                        <categorie>
                            <nummer>02</nummer>
                            <naam>Ouder1</naam>
                            <rubrieken>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0210</nummer>
                                    <naam>Voornamen</naam>
                                    <waarde>Jane</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>Jane</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                                <rubriek>
                                    <nummer>0230</nummer>
                                    <naam>Voorvoegsels geslachtsnaam</naam>
                                    <waarde>van der</waarde>
                                    <omschrijving>van de</omschrijving>
                                </rubriek>
                            </rubrieken>
                        </categorie>
                    </categorieen>
                </persoon>
            </resultaten>
        </ns2:gbavAntwoord>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I've got a working solution in xsl, but it's not very elegant, with a lot of doubles.
The `<xsl:if test="not </>` code is needed multiple times, i also check for the same element in the for-each loop.

```
 <xsl:for-each
                        select="/S:Envelope/S:Body/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.competent.nl/gbav/v1' and local-name()='gbavAntwoord']/resultaten/persoon">

                        <xsl:for-each select="current()/categorieen">

                            <xsl:for-each select="current()/categorie">
                                <xsl:variable name="currentCategorie" select="nummer/text()"/>

                                <xsl:for-each select="current()/rubrieken">

                                    <!-- 230, voorvoegsel geslachtsnaam, kan leeg zijn. Element moet dan wel opgenomen worden -->
                                    <xsl:if test="$currentCategorie='01' or $currentCategorie='05'">
                                    <xsl:if test="not (rubriek/nummer/text()='0230')">
                                        <P1010230>not available</P1010230>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                     <xsl:for-each select="current()/rubriek">

                                        <!-- per categorie de juiste rubrieknummers uitlezen -->
                                        <xsl:if test="$currentCategorie='01'">
                                            <!-- <varValue> <xsl:value-of select="$currentCategorie"></xsl:value-of></varValue>
                                             <Pl010120> <xsl:value-of select="waarde/text()"></xsl:value-of>  </Pl010120>  -->

                                            <xsl:if test="nummer/text()='0120'">
                                              <Pl010120>
                                                  <xsl:value-of select="waarde/text()"/>
                                              </Pl010120>
                                            </xsl:if>
```

The bottom line: is it possible to use a  or another xsl construct/function to accomplish this in a better way then i've come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a very general one and it appears you do not really have a problem, so to speak. Stackoverflow is not really the place to ask for code reviews (à la: "How could this be programmed more elegantly?"). The right place for this is the [Code Review StackExchange Site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

But since I'm writing anyway, yes, there is ample room for improvement in your code.

**Misusage of for-each**

`for-each` (and loops in general) is a procedural construct that is often overused by beginners of XSLT, that is, used in the wrong place. All of your `for-each` elements could be rewritten in separate templates, which is the more functional way of organizing a stylesheet. All your element names are statically known beforehand and the loops are relatively simple.

**if vs. [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-PredicateExpr)**

As you have noticed, there are a lot of `xsl:if` elements in your code. This, too, can be accomplished by writing separate templates with predicates. For example, the following condition:

```
<xsl:if test="nummer/text()='0120'">
```

could be written in a separate template as:

```
<xsl:template match="nummer[.='0120']">
```

**Abbreviations**

Although your code is syntactically correct, there are ways to shorten it considerably. There is no need to prefix expressions with `current()`, as in:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current()/categorieen">
```

since the context of this `for-each` is the current node anyway. Writing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="categorieen">
```

will do exactly the same. Likewise, `text()` is rendundant in many places, for example:

```
<xsl:if test="nummer/text()='0120'">
```

because an XSLT processor implicitly selects the text nodes of an element in a comparison like this. So, this:

```
<xsl:if test="nummer='0120'">
```

is the same.

**Namespaces**

You do not show your entire stylesheet, but it seems you do not declare the namespace `http://www.competent.nl/gbav/v1` in your stylesheet. Instead, you test for this namespace in an XPath expression:

```
namespace-uri()='http://www.competent.nl/gbav/v1'
```

This could indeed be done more elegantly. Usually, all namespaces are declared on the `xsl:stylesheet` element and later referred to by their prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.competent.nl/gbav/v1">
```

Then, you can refer to an element in this namespace with `ns2:gbavAntwoord`.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! And you're correct with your remark about me being a xsl beginner ;-).

I've spent some more time on this problem last week, and i'm down to a solution with 1 <for each> statement and a more sophisticated xpath: <xsl:value-of select="$fullXML/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:gbavAntwoord/resultaten/persoon/categorieen/categorie[nummer=$categorieNr]/rubrieken/rubriek[nummer=$rubriekNr]/waarde/text()"/>
Using a variable to create the element name: '<xsl:element name="{concat('PL',current())}">